# Looking for Gaming Machine, Laptop or Desktop

Tags: laptop, gaming, desktop

I'm looking for desktop/laptop to replace my current one. I have ~$800(based on laptop price) for budget. I like your suggestion on this matter.

My laptop choice is: Lenovo y520

- i5 7300hq
- gtx1050 4gb(not ti)
- 1tb hdd
- 4gb ram(i'll upgrade this to either dual 12gb or single 8gb)

Price=~$745
Price+additional memory=~$820

Planned desktop spec:

- i5 7400
- gtx1050ti 4gb
- 1tb hdd
- 8gb ram
- cheapest motherboard
- cheapest psu with 80+ bronze
- ips led tv 32" for monitor (i choose tv because i like bigger screen
  and is cheaper, i won't budge on this)
- keyboard+mouse

Total price=~$770

I'll use this for gaming i play mostly jrpg and some western(?)rpg, i won't play witcher 3(i don't like the first one) but if this come into consideration at least i want current gen console quality detail @27-30fps and 1080p for more demanding games.

I also need this for college (programming, word processing, light image editing, etc). Depends on what i buy, i will also buy led tv for bigger display(laptop) or low-end laptop for my replacement(desktop) so if you recommend desktop please recommend me a good low-end laptop fo $250-300 also.

If you have a more powerful pc setup in the same price range please do suggest​, but the price here is usually $10-30 higher than msrp. I can't change the laptop choice though because this is the only one that fit my budget in my place. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm not rushing to buy the machine, so if there is an upcoming better solution that will fit my price range i'll gladly wait, the latest is maybe q2 next year because my current laptop physically sadden me.
For the low-end laptop to accompany the desktop (if you recommend this) my top choice is acer switch one(for diversity, etc), if you have other recommendations i prefer something lightweight but still able to do light programming.

Comment: Be careful with skimping on the PSU. A bad power supply can end up destroying your system. Also your specs are way more than you need for simple programming and non triple a 3d games.

Comment: Desktop graphics are going to be a significant improvement over laptop graphics, especially a Ti over a non-Ti card.  Without specific game spec requirements....but it might not make a huge difference for you.  Something to consider.

Comment: @bennett i'll also play AAA 3d rpg games if some catch my interest, my current system can play da: Inquisition with medium setting but with unstable 30 fps(mostly below), i hope my new machine can play it with high-highest setting with stable above 30fps(60fps is of course preferred). Can you recommend me a good psu under $50. And if possible amd equivalent of my planned setup, i'm a bit out of touch with the current gen amd cpu and gpu.

Comment: checkout [pc part picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) to help you put together the cheapest possible rig. For finding equivalent AMD cpus to Intel use [Benchmarks](http://cpuboss.com/), and for GPUs check their [benchmarks](http://gpuboss.com/) too. Benchmarks allow you figure out how your rig will perform without constantly being in touch with the current generations of cpu and gpu.

Comment: after doing some research i get this configuration. for intel: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/KBTxpb , and amd: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/rKhL3F. i'll consider buying rx470 if i have some budget left. After some consideration i'll probably go desktop, but i'll wait a bit more before buying.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths, Re: Desktop graphics, NVidia Pascal actually has identical core configs for desktop and mobility. Performance shouldn't be much differentiated until throttling kicks in, though I've not heard how much that affects things. However, Ti vs non-Ti is up to 30% difference (usually less though) for the 1050/ti.